# Using documentParser function in Teradata Aster

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-aster, sql-mr

I'm working with Teradata's Aster and am trying to parse a pdf(or html) file such that it is inserted into a table in the Beehive database in Aster. The entire pdf should correspond to a single row of data in the table.

This is to be done by using one of Aster's SQL-MR functions called `documentParser`. This will produce a text file(.rtf) containing a single row produced by parsing all the chapters from the pdf file, which would be then loaded into the table in Beehive.

I have been given this script that shows the use of `documentParser` and other steps involved in this parsing process -

```
/* SHELL INSTRUCTIONS */
--transform file in b64 (change file names to your relevant file)

base64 pp.pdf>pp.b64

--prepare a loadfile
rm my_load_file.txt


-- get the content of the file
var=$(cat pp.b64)

-- put in file
echo \""pp.b64"\"","\""$var"\" >> "my_load_file.txt"


-- create staging table 
act -U db_superuser -w db_superuser -d beehive -c "drop table if exists public.cf_load_file;"
act -U db_superuser -w db_superuser -d beehive -c "create dimension table public.cf_load_file(file_name varchar, content varchar);"


-- load into staging table
ncluster_loader -U db_superuser -w db_superuser -d beehive --csv --verbose public.cf_load_file my_load_file.txt


-- use document parser to load the clean text (you will need to create the table beforehand)

act -U db_superuser -w db_superuser -d beehive -c "INSERT INTO got_data.cf_got_text_data (file_name, content) SELECT * FROM documentParser (ON public.cf_load_file documentCol ('content') mode ('text'));"

--done
```

However, I am stuck on the last step of the script because it looks like there is no function called `documentParser` in the list of functions that are available in Aster. This is the error I get -

```
ERROR:  function "documentparser" does not exist
```

I tried to search for this function several times with the command `\dF`, but did not get any match.

I've attached a picture which present the gist of what I'm trying to do.

[SQL-MR Document Parser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eluSG.png)

I would appreciate any help if any one has any experience with this.

Answer (score 0):

What happened is that someone told you about this function `documentParser` but never gave you the function archive file (***documentParser.zip***) to install in Aster. This function does exist but it's not part of the official Aster Analytics Foundation (AAF). Please contact person who gave you this info for help.

`documentParser` belongs to so-called field functions that are developed and used by the Aster field team only. Not that you can't use it, but don't expect support to help you - only whoever gave you access to it.

If you don't have any contacts then next course of action I'd suggest to go to [Aster Community Network](https://aster-community.teradata.com) and ask question about it there.